# How to make apk from base without using third party app?

Tags: apk

I am planning to create a smartphone app for my website. I've searched everywhere, but it seems like all suggest to use apps, like `andromo`, `appmaker`, and more.

While I want to start from the bottom, it's harder not the important thing I can know what frameworks are needed so I become more free if I want to change or add style according to my will.

Like when creating a website, I prefer to organize `HTML` templates manually, than using `CMS wordpress` or others. So I think you guys have understood what I mean.

So, can I do that?
All the answers must be appreciated, and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for native android application development you need to develop it in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html) or [java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm) using Android SDK. There are some other languages can use also.

check this also: 
https://www.androidauthority.com/develop-android-apps-languages-learn-391008/

Comment: this using `Android studio`? is there a way to make it directly in `notepad++` and saved with a certain extension?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You need to have the support of android sdk or ndk

Comment: Check the Notepad++ language supports:http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files